# How to change the value in Html.TextBox for using Jquery and Json?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

In the create view what i am trying to do is when you choose a name from the dropdown list to fill the Login html.TextBoxFor automatically with his details.

Currently the Login textbox remains empty when i choose a person from dropdown list.

So i ve got my json object and tested as well my sql which is fine so i suppose the issue must be somewhere in jquery.

I would be glad if you could help me find the error.

**View :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>User</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserLogin)</div>
            <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserLogin, new {id ="LoginId" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserLogin)</div>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserFullName)</div>
            <div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownList("UserFullName", ViewBag.UserFullName as SelectList, "Select a User", new { id = "UserID" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserFullName)</div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit"
                       value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset> }
        <div>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#UserID').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetUserForm")',
            data: { FullName: $('#UserID').val() },
            success: function (results){
                var login = $('#LoginId');
                login.empty();

                $.each(results, function () 
                {
                    login.val(this.ID).text(this.Value);
                });
            }});
        });
        </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var names = StaffDB.StaffData.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", s.Forename1, s.Surname)
    }).ToList();
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.UserFullName = new SelectList(names, "FullName", "FullName", user.UserFullName);
    return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetUserForm(string FullName)
{
    //pseudo code
    var data = from s in StaffDB.StaffData
               where s.Forename1 + ' ' + s.Surname == FullName
               select new
               {
                   Value = s.Login,
                   ID = s.ID
               };
    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: .... uhm... maybe is useful to have the generate HTML (browser view HTML source) by asp.
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserLogin, new {id ="LoginId" })` is an input or a textarea?

Comment: Its an input...
<input id="LoginId" name="UserLogin" type="text" value="" />

Comment: What is strange is that even if i hardcode it the value is still empty !
$.each(results, function () {
                    login.val("test").text("test text");
                });

Comment: what format has the result?
HTML? JSON? ARRAY? maybe you can't `each()` result because it isn't parsed by javascript.
grate way to debug is to add a `console.log` (or brekpoint) inside your success fucntion to know the value of `results` : `console.log(result);` an maybe a `console.log()` inside the `each()` function to know if you enter in the loop one time...

Comment: is it actually coming inside change() function and hitting your code-behind?

Comment: I just found out in my console that i get this error :

POST http://localhost:57707/User/GetUserForm 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
send jquery-1.8.2.js:8416
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.8.2.js:7968
(anonymous function) Create:1458
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.2.js:3063
elemData.handle.eventHandle

Comment: error 500 is a server side error... i can help you only in javascript :/.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is while returning the json, In MVC by default Jsonresult is "Deny get", so you have add "Allow Get".

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetUserForm(string FullName)
    {
        //pseudo code
        var data = from s in StaffDB.StaffData
                   where s.Forename1 + ' ' + s.Surname == FullName
                   select new { Value = s.Login, ID = s.ID };


        if (data == null)
            return Json(null);

        return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```